# Missing argument 2 for a custom function widgets_init

Tags: functions, widgets, sidebar

I am using a theme_mod string from customizer to generate custom sidebar, but it is called from another function. This is my code:

```
function call_sidebar_function() {

    if ( get_theme_mod( 'enable_sidebar' ) ) {
        $name = "mySidebarName";
        $numberOfSidebars = get_theme_mod('number_of_sidebars');
        generate_sidebars($name, $numberOfSidebars);
    }
}

function generate_sidebars($name, $numberOfSidebars) {
    $i = 1;
    foreach ($numberOfSidebars as $sidebar) {           
        register_sidebar(
            array(
                'name' => $name.$i,
                'id' => $name.$i,
            )
        );
        $i++;
    }
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'generate_sidebars' );
```

Comment: There is no call of function `widget_init` in your posted code. So it's pretty hard to say, what is wrong exactly...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`widgets_init` isn't a function, it's an action hook. The callback you specify for that hook is `generate_sidebars` which requires two parameters, but the `widgets_init` hook doesn't pass any parameters to its callbacks.

I think what you're trying to do is this:

```
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'call_sidebar_function' );
```

Which will call the `call_sidebar_function()` function which will then call the `generate_sidebars()` function with the correct parameters.